# Complex Solr Faceting

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I want to do complex faceting inside json.facet block. My question is, can this is done in Solr 5.x?

```
json.facet={my_stats: {terms:{field:field_x, facet:{avg_sales:"avg(sale_price)",avg_days : "avg(sub(NOW/DAY - year_bought)/365)"}}}}
```

Is the function sub() allowed inside a facet function like avg()? I am trying to subtract year_brough TrieDate from current date and divide it by 365 to get average number of days. In my case Solr keeps complaining that NOW is not a field.

Is this allowed inside facet function?

```
"avg(sub(NOW/DAY - year_bought)/365)"
```

Answer (score 1):

This was worked for me (use div function):

"avg(div(sub(NOW/DAY, year_bought), 365))"

Comment: I realized that my error of referring to sub(NOW/DAY - year_bought) was wrong. Thanks for the direction with the div() function. It worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Also, NOW/DAY doesn't work when i use json.facet ... not sure why.